# How can I detect if the user was deleted from Firebase auth?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Two apps are in the same Firebase project. One app deleted a user from Firebase Auth. But another app still get user uid from somewhere, maybe cache, and access the data in Firebase database with Auth's uid too. 
I mean I can still get "user.uid" by `let user = FIRAuth.auth().currentUser`, if keeping sign-in.

The apps both set `FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true`.

I would like to sing out or refresh cache at all apps if the user was deleted from Auth accordingly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve it by doing this inside `appDelegate`:

```
//Check if user does exists
    func checkUserAgainstDatabase(completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool, _ error: NSError?) -> Void) {
        guard let currentUser = Auth.auth()?.currentUser else { return }
        currentUser.getTokenForcingRefresh(true) { (idToken, error) in
            if let error = error {
                completion(false, error as NSError?)
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                completion(true, nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

And you can do something like this after checking with the above function in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

If user does exist:

```
self.window?.rootViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomTabBarViewController")
```

else:

```
self.window?.rootViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WelcomeViewController")
```

And to test if it did work simply remove user manually from the Auth manager in the Firebase Console. So like this it should just show the welcome screen if user has been deleted.

Comment: Thank you for perfect solution! "error.localizedDescription" shows "There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted."

Comment: No problem :) Happy to help-

Comment: I have two questions. First, is this will work offline as well? like if the user is offline he will still be able to use the app. Second, if the user is connected from two different devices, and delete the account from one device (while the other device is still connected). How will the other device will get notified the account was deleted? so the device will sign out.

Answer (score 1):

with Firebase 4.0 it would look like this:

```
func checkUserAgainstDatabase(completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool, _ error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else { return }
    currentUser.getIDTokenForcingRefresh(true, completion:  { (idToken, error) in
      if let error = error {
        completion(false, error as NSError?)
        print(error.localizedDescription)
      } else {
        completion(true, nil)
      }
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

EJZ and Tarvo Mäesepp answered it beautifully.

You can basically implement a function like this, if another approach is needed:

```
func signOutIfUserDeleted() {
    Auth.auth().currentUser?.getIDTokenResult(forcingRefresh: true) {
        (authResult, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error: \(err)")
            try? Auth.auth().signOut()
        } else if (authResult == nil) {
            try? Auth.auth().signOut()
        }
    }
```

Optionally, you can use the function in the `viewWillAppear` method if you are using storyboard or you can use it within `onAppear` if you are working with SwiftUI in order to sign out if the user is deleted.